# fork exec wait loop for a command line entered value

Tags: c, linux, fork, exec, wait

I'm trying to `exec` a file within another file for maximum 5 times and save results. I use a fork-exec-wait in a for loop, this is how it looks like:

```
    for(i = 0; i< Number_of_Processes; i++){
           pid = fork();
           if(pid == 0)
           {
                 execl(...);
                 exit(EXIT_Failure);
           }
           else if(pid > 0)
           {
                 wait(&status);
                 result = WEXITSTATUS;
           }
}
```

The problem is, it executes the second file for first time correctly and then reprints the first result for 5 times(or whatever the user entered)
I tried so many other ways, like break when it's `pid == 0` but it didn't work. i couldn't find a proper example of how to use `exec` within a loop so I'm stuck for hours, trying moving functions up and down and get nothing.
Whatever i do, i can't see a second execution of the inner file.

Comment: What result is it printing? By the way, `WEXITSTATUS` is a macro that takes the value of your `status`. See the example [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html).

Comment: @chrisaycock the first line of my result is what i expect based on my code but the second line and the others are just the same as the first one like the exec didn't run more than once

Comment: Since you know what `pid` you are waiting for, I suggest that you use `waitpid` instead of `wait`. You may be catching a wrong child's termination.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was a problem of timing, when i add a `sleep(1)` just before `execl` in child process, it fixed everything and execed needed processes one by one and printed true results

```
    for(i = 0; i< Number_of_Processes; i++){
           pid = fork();
           if(pid == 0)
           {
                 sleep(1);
                 execl(...);
                 exit(EXIT_Failure);
           }
           else if(pid > 0)
           {
                 wait(&status);
                 result = WEXITSTATUS;
           }
}
```